# Inconsistent Number of Samples TF*IDF in Sci-Kit Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification

I have 3 lists of words that belong each to the classes Athlete, Comedian, and Singer in that order. I have vectorized these 3 lists using TF*IDF weighting with sci-kit learn to obtain the x_tfidf matrix below (training data):

```
y = ['Athlete', 'Comedian', 'Singer']
x_tfidf = [[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.01707793
  0.17077928 0.01707793 0.01707793 0.01707793 0.0129882  0.01707793
  0.         0.02597641 0.         0.         0.01707793 0.
  0.         0.06831171 0.         0.         0.0129882  0.03415586
  0.01707793 0.01707793 0.03415586 0.         0.01707793 0.
  0.0129882  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.01707793 0.01707793 0.         0.01707793 0.         0.01707793
  0.         0.         0.01707793 0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.01707793 0.         0.0302595  0.
  0.01707793 0.         0.02597641 0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.03415586 0.01707793 0.55475746 0.01707793 0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.01707793 0.
  0.         0.01707793 0.         0.         0.01707793 0.
  0.         0.03415586 0.06831171 0.01707793 0.         0.03415586
  0.         0.01707793 0.0129882  0.         0.         0.01707793
  0.05195282 0.02597641 0.020173   0.0129882  0.060519   0.02597641
  0.         0.01707793 0.         0.55475746 0.55475746 0.01707793
  0.         0.0302595  0.01707793 0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.01707793 0.         0.03415586 0.         0.
  0.         0.02597641 0.03415586 0.01707793 0.         0.05195282
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.03415586 0.         0.02597641 0.01707793 0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.0129882  0.         0.03415586 0.
  0.05123378]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.00791998 0.00791998 0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.03167991 0.         0.01583996
  0.00602335 0.         0.00791998 0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.00791998 0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.00602335 0.00791998 0.00602335
  0.00602335 0.00791998 0.         0.         0.014033   0.
  0.         0.01583996 0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.00791998 0.         0.         0.57535302 0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.01807004 0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.00791998 0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.00791998 0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.00467767 0.         0.00467767 0.
  0.00791998 0.         0.         0.57535302 0.57535302 0.
  0.         0.028066   0.         0.         0.01807004 0.01807004
  0.03167991 0.         0.03167991 0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.00791998 0.         0.00602335
  0.         0.00791998 0.         0.         0.01807004 0.00791998
  0.         0.         0.         0.00791998 0.         0.
  0.        ]
 [0.00527285 0.00527285 0.00175762 0.01230331 0.01230331 0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.00133671 0.
  0.05800134 0.31546417 0.00175762 0.00351523 0.         0.00175762
  0.00175762 0.         0.         0.         0.00133671 0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.00175762 0.         0.00527285 0.00175762 0.00175762
  0.         0.         0.00175762 0.         0.         0.
  0.00175762 0.00527285 0.         0.00133671 0.         0.00133671
  0.00133671 0.         0.         0.00175762 0.00103808 0.00175762
  0.         0.         0.27268937 0.00351523 0.00351523 0.00175762
  0.         0.         0.         0.11937881 0.         0.0105457
  0.00527285 0.00175762 0.00175762 0.00133671 0.         0.00175762
  0.00175762 0.         0.02460663 0.00527285 0.         0.00175762
  0.00175762 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.00175762 0.         0.00401014 0.         0.00175762 0.
  0.01737726 0.29675019 0.21591993 0.00133671 0.22214839 0.31412746
  0.         0.         0.00175762 0.09654112 0.11937881 0.
  0.00351523 0.00207615 0.         0.00527285 0.00133671 0.00133671
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.00351523 0.00175762
  0.00175762 0.00133671 0.         0.         0.00527285 0.63360177
  0.00175762 0.00703047 0.0105457  0.         0.00351523 0.00935699
  0.         0.         0.31412746 0.         0.00133671 0.
  0.00175762 0.00175762 0.00133671 0.         0.         0.0105457
  0.        ]]
```

My goal is to test various classifiers to compare the outputs of various machine learning algorithms in sci-kit learn. That is, to predict whether the user is an Athlete, Comedian, or Singer based on the list of words that will be used as the test data. I have attempted to use KNN using the following code:

```
def classify(x_tfidf, y):
    knn = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
    knn.fit(x_tfidf, y)
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bow.py", line 115, in <module>
    checkExists()
  File "bow.py", line 28, in checkExists
    get_tags(table)
  File "bow.py", line 34, in get_tags
    format_tags(data)
  File "bow.py", line 56, in format_tags
    vectorize(acc_list)
  File "bow.py", line 86, in vectorize
    classify(x_tag_tfidf, y)
  File "bow.py", line 95, in classify
    knn.fit(x_tag_tfidf, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py", line 765, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 583, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 204, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 3]
```

I have attempted to change "y" into an np array, and np matrix without success. I would be extremely appreciatve if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your error, but I can produce a different error when the number of training samples is smaller than the number of cluster centers that will be used (which defaults to 5 as in your code).

Consider a randomly generated synthetic data set with more data points, and notice that the code, just as you have it, works fine:

```
In [17]: y = ['Athlete', 'Comedian', 'Singer'] * 20

In [18]: x = np.random.rand(60, 139)

In [19]: knn = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()

In [20]: knn.fit(x, y)
Out[20]: 
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=5, p=2,
           weights='uniform')

In [21]: knn.predict(np.random.rand(1, 139))
Out[21]: 
array(['Athlete'],
      dtype='<U8')

In [22]: knn.predict(np.random.rand(1, 139))
Out[22]: 
array(['Athlete'],
      dtype='<U8')

In [23]: knn.predict(np.random.rand(1, 139))
Out[23]: 
array(['Singer'],
      dtype='<U8')
```

Now note that if I reduce the toy data down to 3 samples, I'll see an error:

```
In [25]: x = np.random.rand(3, 139)

In [26]: y = ['Athlete', 'Comedian', 'Singer']

In [27]: knn = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()

In [28]: knn.fit(x, y)
Out[28]: 
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=5, p=2,
           weights='uniform')

In [29]: knn.predict(np.random.rand(1, 139))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-e5a6eff3cd22> in <module>()
----> 1 knn.predict(np.random.rand(1, 139))

~/anaconda/envs/py36-keras/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/classification.py in predict(self, X)
    143         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
    144 
--> 145         neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
    146 
    147         classes_ = self.classes_

~/anaconda/envs/py36-keras/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py in kneighbors(self, X, n_neighbors, return_distance)
    345                 "Expected n_neighbors <= n_samples, "
    346                 " but n_samples = %d, n_neighbors = %d" %
--> 347                 (train_size, n_neighbors)
    348             )
    349         n_samples, _ = X.shape

ValueError: Expected n_neighbors <= n_samples,  but n_samples = 3, n_neighbors = 5
```

If I manually plug in the desired number of neighbors (3), then it works:

```
In [31]: knn = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)

In [32]: knn.fit(x, y)
Out[32]: 
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=3, p=2,
           weights='uniform')

In [33]: knn.predict(np.random.rand(1, 139))
Out[33]: 
array(['Athlete'],
      dtype='<U8')
```

Finally, if you change `x` in my example from a numpy ndarray into a list of lists, via `x.tolist()`, it all works just the same, so it's not related to using a list vs. ndarray for either y or x.